# Installing R without Admin on Mac OS

Tags: r, macos

I know that by title, this question duplicates with a previous, but there was no satisfactory resolution provided.

I am installing R 4.0.0 on a MacOS Mojave. I don't have admin access, and I am not able to obtain it for the foreseeable future.

I have downloaded and extracted the .pkg file into a folder. The folder layout is as follows: [image: folder layout]

If I use terminal to run the following commands:

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=~/Documents/RStudio/r_4.0.0/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
open ~/Documents/RStudio/RStudio.app
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to find libR.dylib in expected locations within R Home directory /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources; 
Unable to find libR.dylib in expected locations within R Home directory /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
```

[image: example error]

I have tried:

```
export R_HOME=~/Documents/RStudio/r_4.0.0/R.framework/Resources
export R_HOME_DIR=~/Documents/RStudio/r_4.0.0/R.framework/Resources
```

I have also tried going into the `~/Documents/RStudio/r_4.0.0/R.framework/Resources/bin/R` file
and manually replacing the file paths with mine. But I still get an error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Referenced from: [My User directory]/Documents/RStudio/r_4.0.0/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

At this point I am at a loss of what I am able to do (anything?) it seems `/Library/Frameworks/...` is hardcoded at some point and I can't do anything about it. Can anyone suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this error when I'm trying to open rstudio without installing R.

I solved it by first installing R from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ and try to re-open the rstudio again.

This will resolve this error on macOS.